# Is there a word or phrase to describe indulging deeply in sorrow, wantingly?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Specifically, by "indulging in deeply negative emotions," I envision a process wherein you're experiencing a deep, wretched kind of emotional pain, but ultimately... almost want to? Not because experiencing the emotions would provide some kind of relief or pleasure; but that overarchingly you feel like you intimately need them, and that you *don't* want respite from them.

"Cathartic" is the closest adjective I can come up with, but I'm not sure if it really fits. My (open to comment) intuition feels like a cathartic action is not **[the act of experiencing the emotions]** itself, but an auxiliary action/task that either **[provides relief from the emotions]**, **[allows one to channel the emotions]**, or otherwise **[is done alongside, as a part of, or in addition to]** the act of experiencing the emotions. E.g.

- A cathartic action would be like *physically* having a sizeable stress ball in both hands, and clenching into them as hard as you can.
- In contrast, visually imagine 'embracing' emotions, but more intensely- as if when your arms wrapped around them, you were *mentally* grasping and clawing into the emotions like the stress balls.

As to phrases, "drowning in sorrow" is close, but if you're drowning, you probably desperately want it to end, or for something to rescue you from the storm. "Wallowing in sorrow" is similarly close, but I think wallowing might imply a negative connotation of self-pity, patheticism, or narcissism (like remaining unhappy for attention).

I guess if you consider "indulging in emotions" its own abstract task, you could call it cathartic by my description; **but is there anything else that comes to mind, or is my intuition on catharsis just arbitrary?** (ie, the explicitly mental part is just as cathartic as the act of sobbing, screaming, clawing/grasping)

**Samples for single-word candidates:** They laid down and began to sob, deeply, but they didn't want respite...

- **Verb**:  ...They cried for hours, <word>ing [in/with/through etc.] their despair; desperate for it to stay.
- **Adverb**: ...They cried for hours, <word>[ing/ic]ly indulging their despair; desperate for it to stay.
- **Noun**: ...They cried for hours in a wretched <word>; desperate to keep the emotions.

(e.g. catharting/cathartically/catharsis)

Comment: **Why** are they indulging in the negative emotions? And **how**? Give a detailed example! *Wallowing* or *indulging* certainly seem close. Unless you're talking about a *masochistic* enjoyment of pain, or a sexual fetish for degradation (there's also a religious interest in degradation that *abnegation* might describe but it's not primarily about emotion).

Comment: I can't see how choosing not to at least try to escape from sorrow / grief can not involve self-pity. If _you feel like you intimately need them_, you believe that _experiencing the emotions would provide some kind of relief or pleasure_ (fulfilling a need).

Comment: 'inordinate' can be applied to any behaviour which is excessive : [OED](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/inordinate_adj?tab=meaning_and_use#309393) _not ‘ordered’; devoid of order or regularity; deviating from right or rule; irregular, disorderly; not regulated, controlled, or restrained._. Thus : 'they cried inordinately for hours'. Up-voted +1.

Comment: P.S. I think you meant to say 'wantonly' not 'wantingly' but I might be wrong :)

Comment: **Verb**: ...They cried for hours, **wallowing** in their despair; desperate for it to stay. (No adverb) **Noun**: They cried for hours in a wretched **wallow**; desperate to keep the emotions.

Comment: The adverb "wantingly" is  so rare in English that my spell-checker does not recognize it and I had to look it up to see if it was real. On doing so (OED — subscription) I find that its meaning is "In a needy or desirous manner; yearningly" with an example being "Soon we are staring wantingly toward the sky with eyes secretly pleading for more". Thus it does not mean "deliberately" or the like, which is what your title would imply. I'd edit your question.

Comment: Wallowing "*might imply a negative connotation of self-pity, patheticism, or narcissism*", but isn't that exactly what you are looking for? Wanting to indulge in negative emotions simply tends to be regarded as any of those options (because of societal and historical reasons). 'Catharsis' is certainly not correct.